# a question about the distribution of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Definition : we shall call $p$ a special prime $p_n$, if there is at least one prime of the form $2kp+1$, where $ 1 \leq k \leq n$ .
it is obvious that  we can call any Sophie Germain prime, a special prime $p_1$, or $p_2$, or $p_3$ ....etc. and that because we guarantee that there are a prime number of the form $2 * 1 * p +1$ .

Now, for example, if $p=29023$, and $1 \leq k \leq 20$

so, what is the probability for $p=29023$ to be a special prime $p_{20}$ ?

this is what I think, it is obvious that both of ($2*1*29023+1$, $2*2*29023+1$, $2*3*29023+1$, .......,$2*20*29023+1$) are in the interval [$2*1*29023+1, 2*20*29023+1$] ,

so, if we want to know the probability for $p=29023$ to be a special prime $p_{20}$, we should calculate the probability for a random number to be a prime in the interval  [$2*1*29023+1, 2*20*29023+1$], which is $\frac{\pi [2*1*29023+1, 2*20*29023+1] }{ (2*20*29023+1)- (2*1*29023+1)}$ and then we should multiple it by $20$,

so, the probability for $p=29023$ to be a special prime $p_{20}$, is about $20 \frac{\pi [2*1*29023+1, 2*20*29023+1] }{ (2*20*29023+1)- (2*1*29023+1)}$

so, I want to know if this is the right way to calculate the probability for $p$ to be a special prime $p_n$ ?  and if this is  way is wrong, I need some one to show me how to calculate this probability ?

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $n$?  And it isn't clear what you mean by probability in this context.  Either that number is special or it isn't.

Comment: Regardless, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primepi%282%E2%88%9720%E2%88%9729023%2B1%29-primepi%282%E2%88%971%E2%88%9729023%2B1%29) tells us that there are $84,216$ primes in that interval you mention.

Comment: @lulu there are no conditions on $n$,  and when I say "probability", I mean the probability for $p$ to be a special prime $p_n$

Comment: So, "special" ought to be "$n-$special" or something like that?  Since the definition depends on that parameter $n$.  As for probability, it's fine to ask for the probability that numbers chosen uniformly at random in some interval are prime or not, but of course these numbers are not chosen at random, they are specified.    Anyway, I (or the computer) gave you the number of primes in the interval, which, I think, is all you were looking for.

Comment: @lulu ok, since these numbers are not chosen at random, so, what is the right way to calculate this probability ? please help

Comment: As I say, this isn;t a probability problem.  At least not in any obvious way.  You can try for a heuristic argument in which you pretend that these numbers are randomly chosen in some sense, but you need to defend that assumption.  For instance, all your numbers are odd which dramatically increases the probability that they are prime.

Comment: FWIW, if you take $k=15$ you get a prime, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B2*15*29023%2B1%5D).

Comment: I'm sorry but I am really not clear what you are asking.  I've shown you that $2\times 15\times 29023+1=870691$ is a prime, so the matter is settled, isn't it?  If you want to know the probability at least one of $20$ randomly selected odd numbers in that interval is prime, then you could compute that...is that what you want?

Comment: @lulu  ok, I want to know the probability at least one of $20$ selected odd numbers in that interval is prime, but these $20$ numbers are not chosen at random ? so this is what I am asking about .

Comment: Well.  There are $1102874$ integers in that region so let's say half of those are odd, namely $551437$ (off by one hardly matters here).  Since there are $84216$ primes the probability that a randomly chosen odd number is prime is $\frac {84216}{551437}=0.152721$ which says that the probability that it isn't prime is $.84728$ so the probability that all $20$ are non-prime is $.84728^{20}=.03635$, thus there is a greater than $96\%$ chance that at least one of your numbers is prime.

Comment: @lulu ok, this answer is very helpful, so I hope that you put it as an answer, so I could accept it and upvote it, because I think that this answer must be read, and I have one last thing, all of your steps are claer to me, except this step $.84728^{20}$ , so could you give me an explanation to this step please ?

Comment: If you have $n$ independent events, each of which has probability $p$, the probability that all of them occur is $p^n$ (by the definition of independence).  Here $p=.84728$ is  the probability that the randomly chosen number is composite.

Comment: @lulu ok, thank you very much, could you please give me a reference to (the definition of independence) ?, and please don't forget to put your previous comment as an answer, because I think that it is important answer, thank you very much 

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) is a reference for indepednce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, I will answer this question:   given $20$ odd numbers chosen uniformly at random (and independently) from the given interval, find the probability that at least one of them is prime.

This is mostly a matter of brute force.  We use a computer to determine that the number of primes in the interval is $84216$, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primepi%282%E2%88%9720%E2%88%9729023%2B1%29-primepi%282%E2%88%971%E2%88%9729023%2B1%29).

Then it is a simple matter of determining, $p$, the probability that a (uniformly) randomly selected odd number in the interval is prime.  Since there are $551437 $ odd numbers in the interval we get $$p=\frac {84216}{551437 }=.15272$$

Since the events are independent the probability that all $20$ are composite is $$(1-.15272)^{20}=.03625$$

Thus there is a greater than $96\%$ chance that at least one will be prime.

Worth remarking that a similar analysis shows that there is an $83.26\%$ chance that more than one of the will be prime.  For the given list in the problem, exactly one is prime (by brute force checking) and it at least a little surprising that there is just the one.

Just to be complete, I'll mention that the number $$2\times 15\times 29023+1=870,691$$ is prime.